# how handle "storage/retry-limit-exceeded" firebase storage web while uploading large file of size 1GB

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

**Relevant code:**

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(file_path);
var uploadTask = storageRef.put(file);

uploadTask.on(
    'state_changed',
    function(snapshot) {
        // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
        // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
        var progress = snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100;
        console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
        switch (snapshot.state) {
            case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
                console.log('Upload is paused');
                break;
            case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
                console.log('Upload is running');
                break;
        }
    },
    function(error) {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
        console.warn('Unsuccessful upload', error);
    },
    function() {
        // Handle successful uploads on complete
        console.log('Image upload complete', uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL);
        // Update the info about the post to point to the newly uploaded image
        ref
            .child(eventKey)
            .child('image')
            .set(uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL);
    }
);
```

**Error:**

{
code_: "storage/retry-limit-exceeded",
message_: "Firebase Storage: Max retry time for operation exceeded, please try again.",
serverResponse_: null, name_: "FirebaseError"
}

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors#handle_error_messages), this error means the following:

> The maximum time limit on an operation (upload, download, delete, etc.) has been exceeded. Try uploading again.

Try changing the time limit set for upload retries using [`maxUploadRetryTime`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.firebasestorage.md#firebasestoragemaxuploadretrytime).

Comment: I used s3, works like a charm. I will test your suggestion when having time. thank you.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/s/results?q=maxUploadRetryTime ?