# Getting retry limit exceeded error on uploading a few images to Google Storage

Tags: firebase-storage

I'm not sure what's going on, because I don't get this issue, but a lot of my users report this issue. I have a page that uploads multiple files (the error is happening at 5). Several users report getting the error "storage/retry-limit-exceeded". What's going on? Please help.

In the code below, each error[i][j] gets the same code, which is "storage/retry-limit-exceeded".

My code looks like:

```
function SubmitFiles(){
        pending=true;
        let promises = partsofprobs.map((x,i) => {
            return x.map((y,j) => FileUpload(i,j));
        });
        Promise.all(promises.map(x=>Promise.all(x))).then((values)=>{
            //DO SOME STUFF WITH THE VALUES -- code removed for brevity, since the error is thrown by the other function.
        });
        
}



function FileUpload(i,j){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let file=newpicdata[i][j];
            if(file){
                currentupload[i][j]=true;
                let storageRef = storage.ref();
                let fileRef = storageRef.child(examid+'/'+i+'/'+j+'/'+$currentUser.uid+'/'+newfiles[i][j][0].name);

                let uploadTask = fileRef.putString(file, 'data_url');

                uploadTask.on('state_changed',
                    function(snapshot) {
                        // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
                        let uploadedpercent = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes)*100;
                        console.log('Upload is ' + uploadedpercent + '% done');
                        switch (snapshot.state) {
                            case 'paused':
                                console.log('Upload is paused');
                                break;
                            case 'running':
                                console.log('Upload is running');
                                break;
                            }
                    }, function(err) {
                        console.log("error code: ", err.code);
                        error[i][j]=err.code;
                        currentupload[i][j]=false;
                        reject();
                    }, function() {
                        // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
                        uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
                            uploadedpicsurls[i][j]=downloadURL;
                            success[i][j]=true;
                            currentupload[i][j]=false;
                            console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
                            resolve({url:downloadURL,graded:false,score:null,problemindex:i,part:j,grader:null,notes:[],outof:partsofprobs[i][j],beinggradedby:[]});
                        });
                    
                });
            }else{
                resolve(existingrecord ? existingrecord.solutions[i].parts[j]:{url:null,graded:false,score:0,problemindex:i,part:j,grader:null,notes:[],outof:partsofprobs[i][j],beinggradedby:[]});
            }
        })

    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how handle "storage/retry-limit-exceeded" firebase storage web while uploading large file of size 1GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63311125/how-handle-storage-retry-limit-exceeded-firebase-storage-web-while-uploading-l)

Comment: I don't think so. We're talking about people uploading ~5 images, each not bigger than say 3MB. So, I suspect it's not that it's taking an extremely long time. But of course I'm not sure. It works for me even when I set my upload rates to really slow using chrom dev tools. I was thinking maybe I need to change it so that the uploads happen serially?