# What do I need to do when Firebase storage upload doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-storage

I have been stuck on this problem for a week. Submitting the form, uploadBytes(), works but then it stops at a 0% success rate. I get an error message afterwards saying *FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Max retry time for operation exceeded, please try again. (storage/retry-limit-exceeded).*

Here is my code (some functions were removed for more readability)

```
'use client'

import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { FaPlus, FaMinus } from 'react-icons/fa'
import { GrClose } from 'react-icons/gr'
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { TextField } from '../UI/TextField'
import { MyButton } from '../UI/MyButton'
import { sendRecipe } from '@/lib/recipes/sendRecipe'
import { v4 } from 'uuid';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { sendRecipeImg } from '@/lib/recipes/sendRecipeImg'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { Preloader } from './Preloader'
import { storage } from '@/firebase/config'
import MarkdownEditor from '@uiw/react-markdown-editor';
import { getDownloadURL, ref, uploadBytes, uploadBytesResumable, uploadString } from 'firebase/storage'
import Editor from '../UI/Editor'
import { headingsPlugin, linkPlugin, listsPlugin, markdownShortcutPlugin, quotePlugin } from '@mdxeditor/editor'
import FormControl from '@mui/base/FormControl'

type Props = {}

type FieldValues = Recipe & {
    currIngridientName: string,
    imageFile: FileList,
    content: any,
}

export const AddRecipeForm = ({}: Props) => {
    const { 
        control, formState: { errors }, setValue, 
        watch, getValues, handleSubmit, setError,
        clearErrors, register, trigger
    } = useForm<FieldValues>();

    const [currSelectedImgSrc, setCurrSelectedImgSrc] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [isImageUploading, setIsImageUploading] = useState<boolean>(false);  

    const router = useRouter();

    const formRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);

    const onSubmit = async (data: FieldValues) => {
        const { currIngridientName, ...restData } = data;

        const id = v4();

        if(data.imageFile[0] && data.imageFile[0].size < 71680) {
            setIsImageUploading(true);
            const storageRef = ref(storage, `folder/${data.imageFile[0].name}`);

            const res = await uploadBytes(storageRef, data.imageFile[0]);

            setIsImageUploading(false);
        } else {
            alert('file is too big');
        }
    }

    return (
        <form 
            className='max-w-xl md:max-w-xs w-full' 
            onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
            ref={formRef}
        >
        

            {/* image upload */}
            <div className="">
                <label 
                    htmlFor='imgUpload' 
                    className='cursor-pointer'
                >
                    <span className='text-sm'>Завантажте фото Вашої страви</span>
                    <input type="file" id='imgUpload' { ...register('imageFile', { required: 'Завантажте картинку!' }) } className='opacity-0 invisible w-0 h-0 absolute -z-10' />
                    {/* body of the upload */}
                    <div 
                        className="
                            w-full h-10
                            flex items-center justify-center
                            bg-orange-100 border-orange-400
                            rounded-lg
                        "
                    >
                        <FaPlus className='text-xl'/>
                    </div>

                    {errors.imageFile && <span className='text-red-600 text-sm'>{errors.imageFile.message}</span>}
                </label>

                {/* selected image */}
                {currSelectedImgSrc && 
                    // image wrapper
                    <div className="aspect-video overflow-hidden">
                        <Image 
                            src={currSelectedImgSrc}
                            alt='Обране зображення'
                            width={320}
                            height={320}
                        />
                    </div>
                }
            </div>

            
            {isImageUploading && <Preloader />}

            <MyButton 
                type='submit'
                size='sm' 
                className='mt-2'
            >
                Зберегти
            </MyButton>
        </form>
    )
}
```

**Thanks.**

I **added** size limiter and **provided** uploading to a client, I believe the problem is not with Firebase storage settings because I **tried** the same with one of my working Firebase-storage project and I still get the same error. I have no idea what to do next

P.S: Sorry if ever I used my words wrong

Comment: I haven't had this before, but did you see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63516338?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes, but the link in answer isn't working