Saving an image from a URL to firebase storage not working
I have a problem with saving the response to firebase cloud storage and then saving that url to the db, but it doesn't work I am logging a lot of stuff, but none actually log and I have no errors just after I make the generation it just doesn't do the things after that
here is my api endpoint:
    import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
    import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
    import Replicate from "replicate";
    import prismadb from "@/lib/prisma";
    import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";
    import { randomBytes } from "crypto";
    import { storage } from "@/lib/firebase";
    
    const replicate = new Replicate({
      auth: process.env.REPLICATE_API_TOKEN!,
    });
    
    export const maxDuration = 300;
    
    export async function POST(req: Request) {
      try {
        const { userId } = auth();
        const body = await req.json();
        const { prompt } = body;
        const id = randomBytes(20).toString("hex");
    
        if (!userId) {
          return new NextResponse("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
        }
    
        if (!prompt) {
          return new NextResponse("Prompt is required", { status: 400 });
        }
    
        const response = (await replicate.run(
          "pnickolas1/***:***",
          {
            input: {
              prompt: `${prompt}, black and white coloring page, simple`,
              width: 800,
              height: 1600,
              negative_prompt: "complicated, a lot of details, colors",
              scheduler: "K_EULER",
            },
          }
        )) as string[];
    
    
        const res = await fetch(response[0]);
        const blob = await res.blob();
        const storageRef = ref(storage, `${userId}/${id}`);
        const snapshot = await uploadBytes(storageRef, blob);
    
        console.log(snapshot.metadata.fullPath);
    
        await prismadb.coloringSheet.create({
          data: {
            imgUrl: snapshot.metadata.fullPath,
            prompt: prompt,
            userId: userId,
          },
        });
        console.log("Image URL saved successfully!");
    
        await prismadb.user.update({
          where: {
            userId: userId,
          },
          data: {
            credits: {
              decrement: 1,
            },
          },
        });
    
        return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(response));
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("[VIDEO ERROR]", error);
        return new NextResponse("Internal error", { status: 500 });
      }
    }

Sometimes I get this error:
[VIDEO ERROR] [StorageError [FirebaseError]: Firebase Storage: Max retry time for operation exceeded, please try again. (storage/retry-limit-exceeded)] {
  code: 'storage/retry-limit-exceeded',
  customData: { serverResponse: null },
  status_: 0,
  _baseMessage: 'Firebase Storage: Max retry time for operation exceeded, please try again. (storage/retry-limit-exceeded)'
}

I tried everything I asked every possible ai assistant here is my firebease initialization:
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration

    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "****",
      authDomain: "***.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "***",
      storageBucket: "***.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "***",
      appId: "***",
    };
    
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    
    export const storage = getStorage(app);


Did you search on the internet for similar error messages? You would find a similar SO question with an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63311125/how-handle-storage-retry-limit-exceeded-firebase-storage-web-while-uploading-l

I did this question doesn't answer my question
